# How to redirect other page in Alert React Native

Tags: react-native, alert

i'm new in React Native. and i want to redirect from alert click in react native. but, still error
this is my code. thanks

```
 render() {
  return (
       <View style={styles.Footer}>
            <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => Alert.alert(
                  'Logout',
                  alertMessage,
                  [
                    {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed!')},
                    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => this.onButtonPress()},
                  ]
                )}>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                  <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Logout</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
  }

onButtonPress() {
    const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home'})
      ]
    })
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
  }
```

Comment: What kind of error you get ?

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.dispatch') . this error @Avdept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to bind `this` to onButtonPress so it has proper scope.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.onButtonPress = this.onButtonPress.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have that `onButtonPress` inside the parent container and then pass it as a prop to `CustomDrawerContentComponent` where executing code is: `{text: 'OK', onPress: () => props.onButtonPress()}`.

Currently you have no `this.props.navigation`. Besides your function is outside the component scope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call **onButtonPress** instead of  **onButtonPress()**

```
                Alert.alert(
                            'FingerPrint Authentication',
                            'Would you like to authenticate using fingerprint ?',
                            [
                              {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed!')},
                              {text: 'Yes', onPress: this.onButtonPress},
                            ],
                            { cancelable: false }
                          )


     onButtonPress = () => {
          this.props.navigator.push({
             name: 'Home',
             title: 'Home',
          });
       }
```